# Group elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

I made a quick template to explain what I am trying to achieve:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJWrjO

As you can see, there is two classes ofelements. `.one` and `.two`

I want to group the following elements with each other via css. This will be a visual grouping; not a structural grouping.

Shortly, what I want to do is, to give `margin-top` to the first element for each class cluster, and `margin-bottom` to the last element of each cluster.

So, depending on my example here are the clusters:

```
1,2,3,4         - red cluster
5,6,7           - cyan cluster
8,9             - red cluster
10,11,12,13,14  - cyan cluster
15              - red cluster
16,17           - cyan cluster
```

So according to this structure, for instance, div5 would have a `margin-top` and div7 would have a `margin-bottom`.

Or, div5 would have a `margin-top` and div8 would have a `margin-top` (similar result with the previous statement)

Any kind of solution that allows visual grouping of the similar classed items that follow each other, is accepted.

No JS, only CSS.

Comment: Is it fixed structure? Or ll change?

Comment: it's not a fixed structure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you can't combine `:last-child` with `.class` selector, it's hard to assign `margin-bottom` to the last element of a cluster. But you can detect the switch to another cluster by using `+`:

```
.one + .two, .two + .one {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

See the ***[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvozeZ)***.

EDIT regarding comment asking for a general rule:
There's not a general rule like this I am aware of which would work right now, since CSS doesn't provide anything like `:nth-of-class` nor does it support back references to classes of previous selectors. So you can't do anything like

```
.{class-variable} + :not(.{class-variable})
```

but if you have a list of all *possible* classes, you could do something similar:

```
.one + :not(.one), 
.two + :not(.two) {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

You would need to repeat that for every class that is in the list. See ***[DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEYYNW)*** which has three different classes.

When generating the output, you would need to collect all classes in an array and could create an additional style element in your output to avoid to adapt your CSS every time. In PHP, this could look like

```
$style = '';
foreach ($classes AS $class) {
    $style .= '.' . $class . ' + :not(.' . $class . '), ';
}
if ($style != '') {
    $output = '<style>' . substr($style, 0, -2) . ' { margin-top: 50px; }</style>';
}
```

Comment: While you are at it, there's also `~`, the siblings selector. Just in case you can use that as well.

Comment: Can a similar effect be done as a general rule? My classes are currently id-based, and they're not pre-defined, so I can't do a grouping like this without pre-defined classes. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect current possibilities to do something like that.

Comment: You are very welcome! Keep it up and it will be easy to understand. Be sure to go through all possible selectors in order to be able to create such tricks yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show an alternative, you could order your clusters in the markup by assigning a `data-cluster` attribute:

```
<div class="two" data-cluster="red">6</div>
```

And then style it as you wish:

```
div[data-cluster="red"] {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div[data-cluster="red"] + div[data-cluster="red"] {
  margin-top: 0; 
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/JimmyRare/pen/zxYOwQ)

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement @Paul 's (excellent) answer, you could approach this problem the other way around by applying the top margin on *all* child elements, then override that margin when a child element is following by a child with the same class.

Like this:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.one + .one, .two + .two {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

**[UPDATED CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/JojKGR)**

One advantage of this approach is that the `:not` selector - which isn't supported by older browsers [such as ie8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility) - isn't necessary.

Here's an example with 3 classes

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-top: 50px;
} 
.one + .one, .two + .two, .three + .three {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

**[CODEPEN 2](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/OPJXME)**

```css
body {
  padding: 64px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 40px;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.one + .one,
.two + .two,
.three + .three {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.one {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.two {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.three {
  background-color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="three">4</div>
<div class="two">5</div>
<div class="two">6</div>
<div class="two">7</div>
<div class="one">8</div>
<div class="one">9</div>
<div class="two">10</div>
<div class="two">11</div>
<div class="three">12</div>
<div class="three">13</div>
<div class="two">14</div>
<div class="one">15</div>
<div class="two">16</div>
<div class="two">17</div>
```

Comment: I like the "thinking reverse" solution. I wish we could use variables in css and instead of putting each combination there, just do something like .{class} + .{class}

Answer (score 1):

check it may be it helps you, what you achive :-

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/4m3e7qmp/)

```
div:nth-child(1){margin-top:10px;color:green}
div:nth-child(17){margin-bottom:10px;color:yellow}
```

Comment: the structure will change, I should probobly note it down to the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Check [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azboJg).

CSS:

```
.one-group div:last-child{
margin-bottom:15px;}

.two-group div:last-child{
margin-bottom:15px;}
```

Comment: Oh wait... group?! What is this?!

Comment: I just picked my answer, but this seems to be even more direct, specially for more number of classes!

Comment: I made the `divs` by groups. Would be much more organized. So with this you could select the `last-child`.

Comment: Oh no, I thought -group is a kind of selector.

Comment: @azhpo you've grouped them in HTML, not in CSS, CSS in that case is trivial. Read the Q: *`" ...items that follow each other"`*